# Why jquery autocomplete load only once time

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

My javascript

```
function do_ajax(){
  $.widget("custom.autocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    ....
   }
var getData = function(request, response) {
  $.ajax({
    url : '//htlsearch01.pegipegi.com/HotelSearchAPI/v1/autocomplete/' + request.term,
    cache : false,
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function proccessData (data){
      ...
    }
  })
}
$("#hotelNameKey").autocomplete({
  source: getData,
  minLength: 3,
  select: function(event, ui) {
    ...
  }
})
}
}
```

Why I run my autocomplete only once time. is there wrong with the structure? Or is possible if I using selector `keypress`, `on`?
Thank you

Comment: Do you have caching turned on? Try adding option cache: false to the $.ajax

Comment: oh no, can you give me an example how to using cache? or the reference. that's very useful for me. Thank you @jeffcarey

Comment: I edited my last comment to tell you how to do it.

Comment: didn't work, I try cache : false and async : false, any idea? @jeffcarey